# Margin Auto Need to be centered

Tags: css, alignment, margin, center

This is my code Im trying to get it centered in the middle of the page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<title>cp</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
  <font face="arial" size="5" color="#000000"><center><b>Control Panel</font></center>
</div>
</style>

<style type="text/css">
.span12{
background: lightblue;
color: while;
padding: 9px 0;
border-radius:5px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px #00BFFF solid;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 50%;
margin-top: 25%;
}
</style>
<div class="span12">
Welcome
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It re-sizes with the page but I cant get the whole thing to be in the center of the page.
I just want the whole thing in the middle of the page

Comment: do you want it to be vertically centered too ?

Comment: What is that unclosed center tag for?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `center` tag and set `margin-top:25%`, It will solve your problem.

 **CSS**

```
.span12{
background: lightblue;
color: while;
padding: 9px 0;
border-radius:5px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px #00BFFF solid;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 50%;
margin-top:25%; /* new */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span12">
Welcome
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejway/)**

Comment: I Removed center tag and did as you said But now its just gone down the page.

Comment: Yea that was perfect but mine doesn't do that

Comment: @user2139212 What is your web browser ?

Comment: @user2139212 Remove this line and try again: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: I know but I need that line can i just close it